# How to compile many java class?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

i got some source code here. the thing is that they are separated to one another. How can i compile them all? cause im use to compile single class only

Answer (score 6):

More than one class means a project :).

Have you considered using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)? Makes life much easier and no need to compile at the console.

You could also use the Ant [`javac` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for example ([Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a nice build tool, easy to understand and work with).

Or you could resort to a plain `javac yourPackage\*.java` at the console (javac has lots of options you could use).

Answer (score 0):

> javac *.java // or javac `find . -name
>   \*.java` // then java
>   TheClassWithAMainMethod

**ant** nice tool to compile many classes

Answer (score 0):

if./src - source dir, ./bin - classes dir

> for /r ./src %a in (*.java) do (javac -d ./bin -cp ./bin %a)