# How to compile main class from command prompt that include other classes

Tags: java

I am trying to run java project from command prompt. But when i type

```
javac BatchImport.java
```

then i get the erros. Here is the screen shot of those errors

[image: Compile Errors]

Here is the log

```
D:\LS360BatchImportIntegration\src\main\java\com\softech\ls360\integration>dir

08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          .
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2013  05:03 AM            11,707 AbstractBatchImport.java
08/05/2013  04:06 AM             1,591 BatchImport.java
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          email
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          file
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          ftp
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          sftp
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          util
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          vintners
08/05/2013  05:47 AM    <DIR>          webservice
           2 File(s)         13,298 bytes
           9 Dir(s)  122,904,571,904 bytes free

D:\LS360BatchImportIntegration\src\main\java\com\softech\ls360\integration>javac BatchImport.java
BatchImport.java:12: package com.softech.ls360.integration.util does not exist
import com.softech.ls360.integration.util.IntegrationUtil;
                                     ^
BatchImport.java:13: package com.softech.ls360.integration.util does not exist
import com.softech.ls360.integration.util.VU360IntegrationProperties;
                                     ^
BatchImport.java:14: package com.softech.ls360.integration.vintners does not exist
import com.softech.ls360.integration.vintners.Vintners;
                                         ^
BatchImport.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Vintners
location: class com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport
            Vintners vintners = new Vintners(customerName, randomUUIDString);
            ^
BatchImport.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Vintners
location: class com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport
            Vintners vintners = new Vintners(customerName, randomUUIDString);
                                    ^
5 errors

D:\LS360BatchImportIntegration\src\main\java\com\softech\ls360\integration>
```

My main class include other classes as well. And other classes include other classes as well.How can i compile project that have multiple classes in it ?

Thanks

Comment: `javac` is for compiling, not running.

Comment: yes in compiling i ma getting errors. How can i avoid it ?

Comment: So basically, let us tell you how to generally avoid errors in your code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433332/how-to-compile-many-java-class .  This may be a repost, please let me know if the command "javac yourPackage\*.java " helps.

Comment: The error is not legible.If u r running on windows command prompt, you can paste the log above using mouse right click and selecting copy.Then hit enter to take the log to clipboard. Then paste in notepad using ctrl+v. Then put it above. Also can u paste the BatchImport.java?

Comment: @ahulserver  log added

Comment: Seems that some library is missing or not being loaded/found. It would be better if you can paste the BatchImport.java showing the imports as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Jar File to Buildpath in Windows Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914493/add-jar-file-to-buildpath-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 4):

`javac` assumes the current directory is the location of the default package. You are running it from deep inside the source directory structure.

`cd` back out to `src/main/java` directory and use the full path to the file you want to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The error log:

```
BatchImport.java:12: package com.softech.ls360.integration.util does not exist
import com.softech.ls360.integration.util.IntegrationUtil;
```

Indicates that the class `com.softech.ls360.integration.util.IntegrationUtil;` could not be found on the build path. So you need to add the jars to the build path which contain the above class.

I recommend that you use and IDE for running the class with all the classes included in its build-path. Further if you want to get it done through command prompt, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1914518/1291122) SO answer should help you. But I insist that you use an IDE.

Comment: `IntegrationUtil` is not a jar. It is another class in my project. My `BatchImport` class is in package `com.softech.ls360.integration` and IntegrationUtis is in package `com.softech.ls360.integration.util`. I have other packages also . You can see in the log that i provided like `file, ftp,..`. I think i first have to compile those classes that is including in main class. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *LS360BatchImportIntegration* is your **base_directory** of your project. `cd` to the **base_directory**. From there use the following command:

```
javac -d classes src\main\java\com\softech\ls360\integration\BatchImport.java
```

This will compile your classes and put them inside **base_directory\classes** folder.
If your project has external dependencies use `-cp` option in `javac` command